# Controll widget with flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

#### Project

Hi,
I recently discovered flutter bloc and now I'm trying to understand how exactly this works. My goal is to separate logic from widget classes in order to easily manage my projects.

#### Problem

I'm stuck with something that is very simple using classic setState, but I was trying to achieve this with bloc.

Here is an old widget of mine

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return AnimatedOpacity(
   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
   opacity: _opacity,
   curve: Curves.easeInOut,
   child: Text(
     _currentTitle,
     style: TitleTextStyle,
   ),
 );
}
```

Is it possible to control _opacity and _currentTitle from a bloc? Something like this:

```
List<String> titles = ['title1', 'title2', ....];
int myIndex;

@override
Stream<SomeBlocState> mapEventToState(SomeEvent event,) 
async* {

....
if (event is SomeSpecificEvent)
  setWidgetTitle(titles[myIndex]);
....
}
```

I am trying to avoid buiding different state for each possible title, that would be a mess

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try and make the title widget build in a `StreamBuilder` instead. That will give you a clean separation of responsibilities. So that the BLoC doesn't know of any state changes or widget specific things.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return AnimatedOpacity(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      opacity: _opacity,
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      child: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: myBloc.title,
        builder: (_, snap) {
          return Text(
            snap?.data ?? 'Some default',
            style: TitleTextStyle,
          );
        }
      ),
    );
}
```

And you create some logic in your BLoC that emits the title as needed

```dart
List<String> titles = ['title1', 'title2', ....];
int myIndex;
final _myObservableTitles = PublishSubject();

Stream<String> get title => _myObservableTitles.stream;

....
if (event is SomeSpecificEvent)
  _myObservableTitles.add(titles[myIndex]);
....
```

Comment: Hi, Dennis! Can you have a look at my question here? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61711139/why-does-the-state-change-only-one-time

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Looks like you already got a good answer before I woke up :-)

Comment: Yes, it solved my mistake. I thought I should have used a stream there but apparently I just can convert it into a Stream by adding an asterisk sign to async*. And yield key word. So I just had to yield a new state. But anyway thanks for your readiness to help! I appreciate it a lot